# How to find the tightest upper and lower bound linear functions for bounding a continuous scalar function?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous scalar function. How can I find the tightest lower and upper bound linear functions with the same slope $f_l=kx+b_1$ and $f_u=kx+b_2$ such that $f_l(x) \le f(x) \le f_u(x)$ ? In other words, how to find minimum $(b_2-b_1)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).